# Why element is not scrolling exactly as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i want to position my scrolling `div` within the `scrolable` area, right now it is not correctly working, for `second`, `third` time.

**Question:**  always i want my search element to come to top or should be visible

here is what i have:

```js
     var elements = [{
          value: "first",
          label: "first",
      }, {
          value: "second",
          label: "second",

      }, {
          value: "thired",
          label: "thired",
      },
      {
          value: "fourth",
          label: "fourth",
      },{
          value: "fifth",
          label: "fifth",
      },{
          value: "sixth",
          label: "sixth",
      },{
          value: "seventh",
          label: "seventh",
      },{
          value: "eighth",
          label: "eighth",
      },{
          value: "nineth",
          label: "nineth",
      },{
          value: "tenth",
          label: "tenth",
      },{
          value: "eleventh",
          label: "eleventh",
      },{
          value: "twelth",
          label: "twelth",
      },{
          value: "thirtheen",
          label: "thirtheen",
      },{
          value: "fourtheen",
          label: "fourtheen",
      },{
          value: "fiftheen",
          label: "fiftheen",
      },{
          value: "sixtheen",
          label: "sixtheen",
      },{
          value: "seventtheen",
          label: "seventtheen",
      },{
          value: "eighteen",
          label: "eighteen",
      },{
          value: "ninetheen",
          label: "ninetheen",
      },{
          value: "twenty",
          label: "twenty",
      }];

      $('#search').autocomplete({
                minLength: 0,
                source: elements,
                select: function (event, ui) {
                 console.log(ui);
                  
                 $('.selectable').removeClass('selected');

                 $('.selectable[data-id="'+ui.item.label+'"]').addClass('selected');

                  $('.scrollable').animate({
             scrollTop: $('.selectable[data-id="'+ui.item.label+'"]').offset().top
            }, "slow");
                }
      });

            $('.selectable').click(function(){
               $('.selectable').removeClass('selected');
               $(this).addClass('selected');

            });
```

```css
#wrapper{
           margin:50px 0px 0px 300px;
     }
       .scrollable{
           width: 500px;
           max-height: 150px;
           overflow: scroll;
       }
       ul li.selectable{
           list-style: none;
           width: 100%;
           height: 30px;
           background-color: #b5b5b3;
           border: 1px solid black;
           text-align: center;
           color: white;
       }

       ul li.selectable:hover{
           background-color: #5158b1;
           cursor: pointer;
       }       
      .selected{
          background-color: blue !important;
       }

       #search{
           position: relative;
           float: left;
       }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js
"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css">
<div id="wrapper">
    <div>
      <input id="search"/>
    </div>
    <div class="scrollable">
        <ul>
         <li class="selectable" data-id="first">first</li>
         <li class="selectable" data-id="second">second</li>
         <li class="selectable" data-id="thired">thired</li>
         <li class="selectable" data-id="fourth">fourth</li>
         <li class="selectable" data-id="fifth">fifth</li>
         <li class="selectable" data-id="sixth">sixth</li>
         <li class="selectable" data-id="seventh">seventh</li>
         <li class="selectable" data-id="eighth">eighth</li>
         <li class="selectable" data-id="nineth">nineth</li>
         <li class="selectable" data-id="tenth">tenth</li>
         <li class="selectable" data-id="eleventh">eleventh</li>
         <li class="selectable" data-id="twelth">twelth</li>
         <li class="selectable" data-id="thirtheen">thirtheen</li>
         <li class="selectable" data-id="fourtheen">fourtheen</li>
         <li class="selectable" data-id="fiftheen">fiftheen</li>
         <li class="selectable" data-id="sixtheen">sixtheen</li>
         <li class="selectable" data-id="seventtheen">seventtheen</li>
         <li class="selectable" data-id="eighteen">eighteen</li>
         <li class="selectable" data-id="ninetheen">ninetheen</li>
         <li class="selectable" data-id="twenty">twenty</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
 </div>
```

**Please: search and see the positioning, it is not hapenning correctly**

**JSFIDDLE:**https://jsfiddle.net/m9p5rv47/4/

Comment: you need to minus the y position of the scrollable element onto the scrollTop position `var scrollableY = document.getElementById("scrollable-div").getBoundingClientRect().y;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to substract the `offsetTop` of the parent and add the `scrollTop` of the parent,

this will do the trick :

```
$('.scrollable').animate({
    scrollTop: $('.selectable[data-id="'+ui.item.label+'"]').offset().top - $('.scrollable').offset().top + $('.scrollable').scrollTop()
}, "slow");
```

fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/m9p5rv47/37/

```js
$(function() {

  var elements = [{
      value: "first",
      label: "first",
    }, {
      value: "second",
      label: "second",

    }, {
      value: "thired",
      label: "thired",
    },
    {
      value: "fourth",
      label: "fourth",
    }, {
      value: "fifth",
      label: "fifth",
    }, {
      value: "sixth",
      label: "sixth",
    }, {
      value: "seventh",
      label: "seventh",
    }, {
      value: "eighth",
      label: "eighth",
    }, {
      value: "nineth",
      label: "nineth",
    }, {
      value: "tenth",
      label: "tenth",
    }, {
      value: "eleventh",
      label: "eleventh",
    }, {
      value: "twelth",
      label: "twelth",
    }, {
      value: "thirtheen",
      label: "thirtheen",
    }, {
      value: "fourtheen",
      label: "fourtheen",
    }, {
      value: "fiftheen",
      label: "fiftheen",
    }, {
      value: "sixtheen",
      label: "sixtheen",
    }, {
      value: "seventtheen",
      label: "seventtheen",
    }, {
      value: "eighteen",
      label: "eighteen",
    }, {
      value: "ninetheen",
      label: "ninetheen",
    }, {
      value: "twenty",
      label: "twenty",
    }
  ];

  $('#search').autocomplete({
    minLength: 0,
    source: elements,
    select: function(event, ui) {
      
      $('.selectable').removeClass('selected');

      $('.selectable[data-id="' + ui.item.label + '"]').addClass('selected');
      
      $('.scrollable').animate({
        scrollTop: $('.selectable[data-id="' + ui.item.label + '"]').offset().top - $('.scrollable').offset().top + $('.scrollable').scrollTop()
      }, "slow");

    }
  });

  $('.selectable').click(function() {
    $('.selectable').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');

  });
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#wrapper {
  /*margin:50px 0px 0px 300px;*/
}

.scrollable {
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 250px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

ul li.selectable {
  list-style: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #b5b5b3;
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}

ul li.selectable:hover {
  background-color: #5158b1;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.selected {
  background-color: blue !important;
}

#search {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.24/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div>
    <input id="search" />
  </div>
  <div class="scrollable">
    <ul>
      <li class="selectable" data-id="first">first</li>
      <li class="selectable" data-id="second">second</li>
      <li class="selectable" data-id="thired">thired</li>
      <li class="selectable" data-id="fourth">fourth</li>
      <li class="selectable" data-id="fifth">fifth</li>
      <li class="selectable" data-id="sixth">sixth</li>
      <li class="selectable" data-id="seventh">seventh</li>
      <li class="selectable" data-id="eighth">eighth</li>
      <li class="selectable" data-id="nineth">nineth</li>
      <li class="selectable" data-id="tenth">tenth</li>
      <li class="selectable" data-id="eleventh">eleventh</li>
      <li class="selectable" data-id="twelth">twelth</li>
      <li class="selectable" data-id="thirtheen">thirtheen</li>
      <li class="selectable" data-id="fourtheen">fourtheen</li>
      <li class="selectable" data-id="fiftheen">fiftheen</li>
      <li class="selectable" data-id="sixtheen">sixtheen</li>
      <li class="selectable" data-id="seventtheen">seventtheen</li>
      <li class="selectable" data-id="eighteen">eighteen</li>
      <li class="selectable" data-id="ninetheen">ninetheen</li>
      <li class="selectable" data-id="twenty">twenty</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```